# 'react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-vision-camera

I have spent hours trying to solve this problem with:
(using use_frameworks! :linkage => :static for firebase), with
"react-native": "0.72.7",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^3.6.12",

### Full build logs

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/<>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<>-fvpiedjnqebsuqbaqkpkfoakwdhh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/VisionCamera.build/Objects-normal/arm64/JSITypedArray.o /Users/<>/Desktop/<>/repos/<>/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/cpp/JSITypedArray.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'VisionCamera' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

'react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h' file not found
```

#### How were you trying to build the app?

npm i --legacy-peer-deps
npx react-native run-ios

#### Project dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.7.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.6",
    "@react-native/normalize-color": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@types/rn-fetch-blob": "^1.2.4",
    "anymatch": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "i18next": "^22.4.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "npm-check": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.4",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.6.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.91",
    "react-native-pathjs-charts": "^0.0.34",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.21.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.6.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^6.14.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.6.13",
    "react-native-wheel-pick": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^0.2.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "typescript-cookie": "^1.0.6"
  },
```

#### VisionCamera Version

3.6.13

#### Target platforms

iOS

#### Operating system

MacOS

#### UPDATE: SOLVED with this solution: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1121#issuecomment-1840482742